# How to get Firebase target by PHP?

Tags: php, firebase, laravel-5, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building an PHP website. I want to push notification to client(who login to my website) so I use Firebase Cloud Messaging.

I already registered Firebase app and write a function to send message

```
public function sendMessage($data, $target)
{
    //FCM api URL
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    //api_key available in Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> CLOUD MESSAGING -> Server key
    $server_key = 'MY SERVER KEY';

    $fields = array();
    $fields['data'] = $data;
    if (is_array($target)) {
        $fields['registration_ids'] = $target;
    } else {
        $fields['to'] = $target;
    }
    //header with content_type api key
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization:key=' . $server_key
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

But I don't know how to get `$target` to let Firebase send message to.

[image]

Now I want when user register/login on my website, I will request `token` from Firebase and save it to my DB.

Because when I want send message to that user, I need provide target(token) for Firebase. Anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

At first, client should have application that uses your firebase project. 
Then you can sand message to it application, and you have 2 ways to do it:

- You have to acquire his registration token
- His app on smartphone should be registered in some topic, ex. "general".

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are talking. I just want get user token from firebase when user register on my website. Of course token of my website and token of firebase is differrent